# Get springer `\subset`-like math operators

Tags: fonts

There are lot of questions about getting old-fashion templates (even some by me). In general, the answers solve the body font and some symbols. But others like `\subset`, `\cup`, `\in`, etc. remain the same.

I would like to get these symbols like in Springer books. Here I post a photo of what I say (the picture is taken from the Free Preview of [Fulton, Harris](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9780387974958)):
[image]

**ADDENDUM**

This code

```
% RECOMMENDED %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
   

\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                   % please use the style svind.ist with
                   % your makeindex program

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\author{Author name(s)}
\title{Book title}
\subtitle{-- Monograph --}

\frontmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\tableofcontents

\include{acronym}

\mainmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\chapter{One}

\section{one}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation}
x\in X \quad y\succ x \qquad Q(y)z \subset \cap G = \varphi(\alpha)\beta \Gamma
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2-20]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

is the svmono template shared by Springer. It looks like this:

[image]

I think there are some differences, there aren't some?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean with "these symbols"? Please mark them on the image ...

Comment: they look like fairly conventional symbols up to usual differences between fonts, what particular features are you looking for in (say) the `\in` symbol.

Comment: Yes @Mico. I have already said in my question. Notice the `\subset` symbol. It is much more narrow, smaller than usual with `lmodern`. How can I get it?

Comment: if you have the pdf/ebook  of that book you can get the list of fonts used, or you could just ask the authors, it will be some times-like math font but probably not mathptmx

Comment: They look very much like the `SSymbol` fonts, once freely available from Springer's site in a set of Springer fonts based on Adobe Minion. I think the closest you could get by now is with the `MinionPro + MnSymbol` packages.

Comment: @Bernard: I tried to install `MinionPro` but I didn't know :( Is `MnSymbol`free or needs a tree-level installation? And what about `SSymbol`? Really is it free?  Where can I find it?   And I haven't the book.

Comment: I believe MnSymbol is free, as it was designed by the author of the MinionPro package, but the package mentions no license. SSymbol is no more available on  the Springer site (I obtained the `Sminion` fonts pack more than 15 years ago). As to MinionPro, it requires some work from the end user with the LCDF Type Tools, to make type1 fonts from the opentype fonts that come with Acrobat Reader. I guess there might be copyright problems to use them, except for private use.

Comment: @Bernard: Minion Pro font works right in main text. For math fonts Times New Roman looks better. Using `mathspec`package I think gettong a very similar result is possible

Comment: I'm not so  sure Times  for maths fits well Minion Pro for text, but it's a matter of personal taste. Personally, I don't like Times, which is overused. When I use Minion Pro for both, I don't use `mathspec` because when  I tried it (at least 10 years ago),  there were problems with side bearings for exponents and indices. I don't know if `mathspec` has evolved since then, so I stick to Minion Pro  via fontspec, with option `[nomath]`,  and use the `MinionPro` package for maths.

Answer (score 1):

mathptmx is very old and uses characters available at the time, it's not really recommended these days, other times clones get closer eg newtxmath

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}


\begin{document}

$A \cap B \subset C $

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah!! This is looking more.

Comment: I think `mathabx`gives the best (or closest) look.

Comment: @Dog_69 ok glad you got something working, feel free to self answer a mathabx version if you wish :-)

Comment: Thanks @David Carlisle. I think my comment completes your answer and is enough.